# Error: Unable to get available storage types [Eclipse Che]

Tags: kubernetes, eclipse-che

I am trying to install `Eclipse Che version 7.29.1` in an air gapped environment and have run into an issue.  We are using `Helm`, `Chectl`, and `Kubectl` on a Linux EC2 instance that’s connected to a Kubernetes cluster in AWS.

I have followed [this documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/che-7/installation-guide/installing-che-on-aws/) to set it up in a multiuser environment.

Once we figured out how to install in the air gapped environment, the installation went smoothly with no errors.

Here is the issue I am hitting:

[Screenshot of Eclipse Che Error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hPGh.png)

Here is our `ingress` file that is used in conjunction with the one in the docs above:

[Screenshot of Ingress File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdxsG.png)

Here is also our `requirements.yaml` which helm uses to install. Due to an air-gapped deployment, the file property is pointing to “custom-charts” so we can reference these images from our internal image repo:

[Screenshot of our air-gapped Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfmOU.png)

Here is the version of the installed software tools:

Helm:

```
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.2.1", GitCommit:"fe51cd1e31e6a202cba7dead9552a6d418ded79a", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.13.10"}
```

Chectl:

```
chectl/7.30.1 linux-x64 node-v12.22.1
```

Kubectl:

```
 Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17+", GitVersion:"v1.17.9-eks-4c6976", GitCommit:"4c6976793196d70bc5cd29d56ce5440c9473648e", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-07-17T19:00:19Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
 Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18+", GitVersion:"v1.18.16-eks-7737de", GitCommit:"7737de131e58a68dda49cdd0ad821b4cb3665ae8", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-03-10T21:33:25Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Here is the install command we are using:

```
chectl server:deploy --installer=helm --platform=k8s --domain=che.domain.com --multiuser
```

There is not too much information online about this issue.  I have found these:

https://github.com/eclipse/che/issues/19465

And

https://github.com/eclipse/che/issues/19611 which has been closed and patched in the 7.29.0 version, however we are still hitting the issue.

Comment: Welcome to the community! Please add error traces, configs in text, it's much easier to community to help you. Please refer to [DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hello, let's collect all the details in the issue https://github.com/eclipse/che/issues/20097